# Is there any way to get the Acumatica base URL through BLC / graph code?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Is there a way to get the Acumatica Base URL through the business logic code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PXInstanceHelper.HostName`, it returns with your computer's name, or you can use HTTPContext from `System.Web`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Comment: I'm using a development machine with a test instance, and PXInstanceHelper.Hostname gives me:  DESKTOP-7A31D1A/AcumaticaDB222110034, which is my Desktop name plus the acumatica instance name.  I need the IIS URL, which in this case would be http://localhost/AcumaticaDB222110034.   Still not sure how to get this...